# How do I make this regex a valid Java regex?

Tags: java, regex

In [an earlier question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636650/how-would-you-sanitize-the-street-number-out-of-a-postal-address-using-java) about sanitizing postal street addresses, one of the respondents recommended this solution:

```
addressString.replace(/^\s*[0-9]+\s*(?=.*$)/,'');
```

which is perhaps a valid regex call but is not valid in Java.

I unsuccessfully tried to make this valid Java code by changing it to the following:

```
addressString.replaceAll("/^\\s*[0-9]+\\s*(?=.*$)/","")
```

But this code had no effect on the address I tested it with:

```
310 W 50th Street
```

Did I not correctly translate this to Java?

Comment: FYI, you don't need that `(?=.*$)` at the end.  @ElRonnoco corrected himself on that point in his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636650/how-would-you-sanitize-the-street-number-out-of-a-postal-address-using-java/3636787#3636787

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the slashes in Java.

```
addressString.replaceAll("^\\s*[0-9]+\\s*(?=.*$)","")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to take out the slashes at the beginning and end:

```
addressString.replaceAll("^\\s*[0-9]+\\s*(?=.*$)","")
```

They're used to quote regexes in some languages, but Java just uses ""

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the forward slashes at the beginning and end.

For the future, you can probably ask for clarification on the answer itself instead of starting a new question.  I apologize, I was going to ask the person who gave that answer to translate it to valid Java myself but forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to support street names that start with a number:

Try the following Java String:

```
"^\\s*[0-9]+\\s*(?=.*$)".
```